# Switch for specific child type from parent type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an parent class `Action`:

```
export class Action { 
    public change: string;
}
```

And two childs of this `Action` `SpecificAction|ToggleAction`:

```
export class SpecificAction extends Action {
  actuator: string;
}

export class ToggleAction extends Action {
  toggle: boolean;
}
```

Is it possible in TS to construct a switch operator? I try this but do not work

```
processEvent(action: Action) {
    switch (action.constructor) {
      case SpecificAction:
        console.log('is it a SpecificAction'); 
        break;
      case ToggleAction:
        console.log('is it a ToggleAction');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Action child not found');
    }
}
```

I try with `typeguard` but do not work! (`processEvent({change: "mm", actuator: "foo"});` My data come from REST API)

```
processEvent(action: Action) {
    if (action instanceof SpecificAction) {
        console.log('is it a SpecificAction');
    } else if (action instanceof ToggleAction) {
        console.log('is it a ToggleAction');
    } else {
        console.log('Action child not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: there are multiple ways to create a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) depending  on your usecase

Comment: BTW, you suppose to rely on the polymorphism to achieve the same effect. I.e. you have to have some kind of `.Do()` overloads per each implementor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processEvent(action: Action) {
    if ((action as SpecificAction).actuator !== undefined) {
        console.log('is it a SpecificAction');
    } else if ((action as ToggleAction).toggle !== undefined) {
        console.log('is it a ToggleAction');
    } else {
        console.log('Action child not found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something else

```
export class Action { 
    public actionType;
    public change: string;
}

export class SpecificAction extends Action {
  actuator: string;
  actionType: "SpecificAction";
}

export class ToggleAction extends Action {
  toggle: boolean;
  actionType: "ToggleAction";
}
```

and in you switch statement

```
switch (action.actionType) {
    case "ToggleAction":
        ...
    case "SpecificAction":
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

Comment: Do not work. `action: Action` come from API REST `{change: "mm",  actuator: "foo"}` No constructor by typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can check if object is instance of some class by `instanceof` operator. And the implementation of `processEvent` from the question should work. But what I get from the comment is - this data comes from the API. In that case instanceof do not work because these data is just plain js objects and do not belong to any class, so they have no constructors.

In order to have still classes (I assume there will be methods and so on), we need to take the raw data and put them into object constructors. Full implementation:

```
interface Action { 
    change: string;
}
interface SpecificAction extends Action {
  actuator: string;
}

interface  ToggleAction extends Action {
  toggle: boolean;
}

type AnyAction = Action | SpecificAction | ToggleAction;

class Action implements Action{
    constructor(data: Action) {
        this.change = data.change;
    }
}

class SpecificAction extends Action implements SpecificAction  {
    constructor(data: SpecificAction) {
        super(data);
        this.actuator = data.actuator;
    }
}

class ToggleAction extends Action implements ToggleAction  {
    constructor(data: ToggleAction) {
        super(data);
        this.toggle = data.toggle;
    }
}
// type guards
const isResponseSpecificAction = (a: AnyAction): a is SpecificAction => !!(a as SpecificAction).actuator 
const isResponseToggleAction = (a: AnyAction): a is ToggleAction => !!(a as ToggleAction).toggle 

function apiConnectorLayer(responseDataAction: AnyAction) {
  if (isResponseSpecificAction(responseDataAction)) {
    return new SpecificAction(responseDataAction)
  }
  if (isResponseToggleAction(responseDataAction)) {
    return new ToggleAction (responseDataAction)
  }

  return new Action(responseDataAction)
}
```

After that processEvent should work with things returned from `apiConnectorLayer` by using `instanceof`.

```
function processEvent(action: AnyAction) {
    if (action instanceof SpecificAction) {
        console.log('is it a SpecificAction');
    } else if (action instanceof ToggleAction) {
        console.log('is it a ToggleAction');
    } else {
        console.log('Action child not found');
    }
}
processEvent(apiConnectorLayer({ change: '', toggle: true })); // works!
```

Comment: Do not work: `processEvent({change: "mm", actuator: "foo"});` My data come from REST API

Comment: This change everything. You need to explicitlly create object of the class in order to use instanceof. Let me add show you how to do that differently

Comment: @sgrillon take a look